# Javascript event 'mouseenter' triggered twice first time - Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

In my Meteor application, the event 'mouseenter' is triggered twice the first time I put my mouse on the element. After the first time it works correctly.

Also, the event handler is run once when I start the application without moving the mouse.

Here is the code:

```
Template.filters.events({
'mouseenter .filters-box': (event, element)=>{
    var target = Template.instance().$(event.target).children('.filters-popup')[0]
    console.log('enter');
    console.log(target);
    if(!target){
        return;
    }

    var prevWidth = target.style.width;
    target.style.width = 'auto';
    var endWidth = getComputedStyle(target).width;
    target.style.width = prevWidth;

    target.offsetHeight;

    target.style.width = endWidth;

},
'mouseleave .filters-box': (event, element)=>{
    var target = Template.instance().$(event.target).children('.filters-popup')[0];
    console.log('leave');
    console.log(target);
    if(!target){
        return;
    }

    target.style.width = getComputedStyle(target).width;
    target.offsetHeight;
    target.style.width = 0;
}
});
```

This is the output in the browser console:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/
filters.js:26 enter
filters.js:27 undefined
```

Then when I move the mouse in and out of the element:

```
filters.js:26 enter
filters.js:27 <div class=​"filters-popup" style=​"width:​ 0px;​">​…​</div>​
filters.js:26 enter
filters.js:27 <div class=​"filters-popup" style=​"width:​ 0px;​">​…​</div>​
filters.js:44 leave
filters.js:45 <div class=​"filters-popup" style=​"width:​ 0px;​">​…​</div>​
filters.js:44 leave
filters.js:45 <div class=​"filters-popup" style=​"width:​ 0px;​">​…​</div>​
```

The next times I do it only one event is triggered of each type:

```
filters.js:26 enter
filters.js:27 <div class=​"filters-popup" style=​"width:​ 0px;​">​…​</div>​
filters.js:44 leave
filters.js:45 <div class=​"filters-popup" style=​"width:​ 0px;​">​…​</div>​
```

I tried with event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation(); methods, but it still didn't work correctly.

Comment: I am also having this issue with Meteor. even.preventDefault() does nothing for me either. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Many years later, still looking for a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Does your `<div>` contain any child elements? They are probably also triggering a mouseenter event. You can put `event.preventDefault()` at the beginning of your event handler. This should prevent any other events handlers from being triggered.

If the event is triggered when the mouse is inside the div during startup, I would indeed imagine that it gets triggered. If the position/size of the div changes during rendering, you could get it even if the mouse is in a different spot than where the div ends up. A potential solution is to only declare the event handler once your rendering is done, kind of like putting things inside a `Meteor.startup` call.

Comment: I tried with event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation(); with no result...